# How many heroes has Batman created?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe

I know of [Nightwing](http://img01.deviantart.net/f9a2/i/2013/259/9/f/nightwing_by_shamserg-d6ln6o8.jpg), [Batgirl](http://www.tencentticker.com/projectrooftop/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/babs-tarr.jpg) and [Red Robin](http://orig10.deviantart.net/319b/f/2013/150/b/7/red_robin_yj_design_by_bobkitty23-d674mg9.png).

Dick Grayson become's Nightwing and also Red Robin in an alternate reality I think.

Barbara Gordon is Batgirl.

Do anymore of Batman's friends/allies become superheroes?

Comment: I assume we're ignoring all the Robins?  Because there are like a thousand of those little suckers...

Comment: And are you looking for individual characters, or superhero identities?  Because many (most?) characters have held multiple superhero identities, and many (most?) superhero identities have been held by multiple people.

Comment: @Nerrolken Just the individual heroes if that's ok? I know there's been a few Batgirls so I wouldn't really want Batgirl 1 and Batgirl 2 and so on... So Batgirl, Batlad, Batnephew, etc would be great!

Comment: Queue Tina Turner's *We don't need another hero*. ;)

Comment: Well less than how many villains he created.

Comment: @Nerrolken: http://i.imgur.com/G9SkMxr.png

Comment: ...and that's how @PaulD.Waite became my hero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Off the top of my head (and I'll expand this list as I find them):

- [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman)
- [Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_(comics))
- [Nightwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Grayson)
- [Red Hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Todd)
- [Red Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Drake)
- [Batgirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Gordon)
- [Bat-Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bette_Kane)
- [Batwoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batwoman#Kate_Kane)
- [Batwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batwing_(DC_Comics))
- [Black Bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_Cain)
- [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Gordon)
- [Cat Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Robin#Carrie_Kelley)
- [Spoiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephanie_Brown_(comics))
- [Bat-Mite](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Bat-Mite)
- [Ace the Bat-Hound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_the_Bat-Hound)
- [Batman of Zur-En-Arrh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_of_Zur-En-Arrh)
- [Huntress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntress_(Helena_Bertinelli)) (originally a stand-alone character, the Earth-2 version is Bruce Wayne's daughter)
- A number of international Batmen, operating under [Batman Incorporated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Incorporated)

There are also a substantial number of heroes who were recruited and supported by Batman, despite having existed independently before his involvement, and several hero-esque characters who never adopted superhero identities, like Alfred or Lucius Fox or Jim Gordon.

And, of course, out-of-universe, there are probably hundreds of heroes who were created for Batman storylines, without having been created by Batman/Wayne in-universe.

Comment: Very cool! _Batman Incorporated_ is actually a thing? Brilliant!

Comment: I would add Oracle! And Carrie Kelley's Catgirl. And maybe Spoiler.

Comment: I'm really hoping one of them is called Batbat...

Comment: [Batmite](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Bat-Mite)?

Comment: Huntress, especially the Helena Wayne versions.

Comment: Azrael, probably, too.

Comment: Bat-Girl, a distinct character from Batgirl.

Comment: @SplittingAdam  Azrael was created for a Batman story, but (at least according to Wikipedia) Batman wasn't involved in his creation in-universe.  He'd be covered by that last paragraph.

Comment: The original version of The Huntress was a villain. The second was Helena Wayne, the original / golden age Batman and Catwoman's daughter. Then Helena Bertelli, a standalone character, then a new Helena Wayne with the same essential backstory as her predecessor.

Comment: "and several hero-esque characters who never adopted superhero identities, like ... Jim Gordon" Jim Gordon *is* Batman now...

Comment: @Politank-Z  Right, but OP specifically said they didn't care about multiple people sharing the same identity.  "Batman" counts as one character, and Jim Gordon has never adopted a superhero identity *of his own*.

Comment: Green Arrow also strikes me as a candidate... he was a Batman/Robin Hood mashup for a LONG time. Arrow-cave, for Darkseid's sake...

Comment: Plus the attempts at future Batmen, of several flavors. (Rant about the Dark Knight withheld as a public service,)

Comment: How about [Ace the Bat-Hound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_the_Bat-Hound)?

Comment: How about the Batman of Zur-En-Arrh?

Comment: You missed [Terry McGinnis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(Terry_McGinnis))